# Purposefully Embellish Json Schemas That Are Similar For Predictability

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

If we have two Json schemas that are similar to the point where one is basically a subset of the other, logically. Would it be better to purposefully distinguish between the two?

Take the two schema's below for example:

```
{
  "$id": "Schema1.schma.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    }
    "A": {
      "type": "string"
    }
    "B": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "$id": "Schema2.schma.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string"
    }
    "A": {
      "type": "string"
    }
    "B": {
      "type": "string"
    }
    "C": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If we put these two through a validator there will be some trouble because the properties are so similar.  So to fix this scenario we can have all the properties be required as well as not allow additional properties.  However, one gives up the ability to say some properties are, in fact, optional. I'm wondering, as to not give up the benefit of having some properties be optional, it would be better to actually embellish the property names.  That way validation is "simpler".  As an example, this means the `A` property might become `schema1A` and `schema2A`.

I have some schemas in a Javascript environment I will deploy at some point and want to make sure they are in a good place before then.

Comment: what makes you think there is some validation issue?  you can extend the second one with the additional property by using`allOf` so you have a "base" schema and the extended version

Comment: I guess, what I'm trying to say, is that I have a requirement that Schema1 and Schema2 be two distinct data types.  And my code will want to parse the data in different ways depending on this data type.  So in that case I should probably introduce a property defining the type and make that a requirement and every other attribute can more naturally be optional. As well as refactor the commonalities.